# My scss file isn't pulling through correctly, can you tell why?

Tags: html, css, animation

My animated background isn't working and I am not sure why. I took the code from this codepen: https://codepen.io/Mamboleoo/pen/BxMQYQ. It works on codepen but in my virtual environment it doesn't. I am using Flask also.

Here is the home.html I am trying to load:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='scss/background.scss') }}">
<title>Home</title>
{% endblock %}


{% block body %}
<div class="background">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

And my SCSS (stored in static/scss/background.scss:

```
    body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .background {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #3E1E68;
  }

  $particleSize: 20vmin;
  $animationDuration: 6s;
  $amount: 20;
  .background span {
    width: $particleSize;
    height: $particleSize;
    border-radius: $particleSize;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    animation-name: move;
    animation-duration: $animationDuration;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    $colors: (
      #583C87,
      #E45A84,
      #FFACAC
    );
    @for $i from 1 through $amount {
      &:nth-child(#{$i}) {
        color: nth($colors, random(length($colors)));
        top: random(100) * 1%;
        left: random(100) * 1%;
        animation-duration: (random($animationDuration * 10) / 10) * 1s + 10s;
        animation-delay: random(($animationDuration + 10s) * 10) / 10 * -1s;
        transform-origin: (random(50) - 25) * 1vw (random(50) - 25) * 1vh;
        $blurRadius: (random() + 0.5) * $particleSize * 0.5;
        $x: if(random() > 0.5, -1, 1);
        box-shadow: ($particleSize * 2 * $x) 0 $blurRadius currentColor;
      }
    }
  }

  @keyframes move {
    100% {
      transform: translate3d(0, 0, 1px) rotate(360deg);
    }
  }
```

All I am loading is the purple screen, none of the animations :/

Comment: `.scss` file should be processed to `.css` with special tools like https://prepros.io/ . Then you have to link .css in your html.  Your local environment doesn't perform this processing automatically. Indeed your  .scss is correct and resulting .css works well.

Comment: you need to convert your scss file into css.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below type of online tools which will help you to convert scss files to css

For example: https://jsonformatter.org/scss-to-css

You need to convert your scss code to css first. And then in respective HTML file you need to call this .css file and NOT the scss file

Comment: Thanks, I installed a package into vs code that compiles my scss into css.

Comment: that is the better way. Cool!